# Problema al correr 'npm start' despues de crear un proyecto con React

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm, terminal

Dejenme ponerlos en contexto. Recientemente he empezado a aprender react. Yo uso Windows 10 con WSL "windows subsystem for linux" y Ubuntu instalados en adición a esto yo trabajo con Hyper terminal al cual le instalé ZSH y "oh my ZSH".

Actualmente tengo instalado en la terminal (ZSH) Node.js versión (12.1.0) y NPM (6.9.0)

El **problema** empieza luego de crear un proyecto con React al intentar correr el comando **"npm start"**

**Pasos para reproducir el error:**

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

luego de ejecutar NPM start me aparece esto:

```
    events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:431:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:17)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:431:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/roguesquid/.npm/_logs/2019-05-04T14_02_48_006Z-debug.log
```

Y en el log me aparece esto:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.1.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~prestart: my-app@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: my-app@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/c/Users/$9 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: CWD: /mnt/c/Users/luisr/my-app
10 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-app@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /mnt/c/Users/luisr/my-app
16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v12.1.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

PD: Tengo instalado node en Windows tambien y al intentar correr "npm start" sucede lo mismo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solucionado, solo añadir C:\Windows\System32 a la variable del sistema "Path"

Answer (score 0):

No tengo suficiente reputación para comentar,

Verificame que en tú fichero package.json tienes definido lo siguiente:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Estas son las funciones definidas que puede ejecutar NPM